# Android floating button not coming proper

Tags: android

I am using a floating button. The image source I am using is also proper but not sure while setting it is showing it as dot in the center. Screenshot and Code below :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_cg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_4a90e2"
        android:src="@drawable/addbutton"/>
```

[image: Floating Button]

Comment: check your  android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" best thing remove this line

Comment: did you check your icon size??

Comment: use vector drawable

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 android:scaleType="center"
```

make sure your icon size is 24 X24 dp icon

see [this](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/719910/how-to-increase-the-size-of-icon-inside-floating-action-button)   for reference

Answer (score 0):

`fabSize` can adjust as "mini" & "normal".

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24px"
 app:fabSize="mini"    
 android:scaleType="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this way its working fine,

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add_cg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="10dp"

        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#f0f0"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the latest support libraries to your app build gradle file and build your project
dependencies {

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

}

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 android:id="id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24px"
/>
```